# How to decode the utf-8 encoded string with special characters like "&lt;span style=\&quot;color:#ff0000;\&quot;gt;" in android?

Tags: java, android, utf-8

I want to show the color,span,font etc in webview.So the data comes from php webservice.Due to problem in parsing data we encode it using UTF-8 format.I successfully parse the data and insert into the database.But the problem here is that when i want to show that data in webview then it contain some special characters like `"&lt;span style=\&quot;color:#ff0000;\&quot;&gt;"` which means `<span color="#ff0000"/>"`. So here i want to decode that and want result in the format "".

I simply want  `String str = "&lt;span style=\&quot;color:#ff0000;\&quot;gt;";`

```
 public String  decodeMethodUtf(Str)
          {
             //do some coding and decode
                return str;
          }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: An ampersand `&` is missing; should have been `&gt;` in the original text (XML?). If it was editing inside Stackoverflow, use back ticks ` for quoting the code.

Comment: no ampersand & is missing there.. i have more than 20,thousand rows into the database and i want to show them in webview.

Comment: String str = "&lt;span style=\&quot;color:#ff0000;\&quot;&gt;";
          String decoded_string = decdecodeMethodUtf(str);
          Log.e("", ""+decoded_string);//and this is the output = &lt;span style=\&quot;color:#ff0000;\&quot;&gt;

          public String decodeMethodUtf(Str)
          {
             return URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8");
          }
         @JoopEggen

Comment: The string in a question contains invalid terminated amps:`\&quot;` which shouldn't be terminated and it has to be just `&quot;` instead. Also the string contains unneeded semicolon:`color:#ff0000;`. Looks like the given string by itself is invalid initially and it can't be processed actually. The right string should be: `String str = "&lt;span style=&quot;color:#ff0000&quot;&gt;"` and using Html.fromHtml() it will return `<span style="color:#ff0000">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually android does not gives any direct class or method to Decode and remove the all special characters.I spend many hours on web to find this.So now when i find answer i want to share that answer with you.
This can be done by using  org.apache.commons.lang class which is not in android.
So first you have to download the jar file from 
here  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3

after download jar file include that file in your project.
and now one line code is here
decoded_string = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(endoded_string);
and the decoded string is your final string without special characters.

Comment: There's also a newer verssion, commons.lang3, which has a similar method, StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is what you want

```
Html.fromHtml("YOUR TXT").toString()
```

Comment: Actually this works fine and for `Log.d(TAG,"Symbols decoded: "+ Html.fromHtml("&lt;span style=&quot;color:#ff0000;&quot;&gt;"));` it returns valid string like: `Symbols decoded: <span style="color:#ff0000;">`. However initial string in a question contains invalid terminated amps:`\&quot;` which shouldn't be terminated and it has unneeded semicolon as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps.

```
   public String decodeMethodUtf(Str)
   {
      return URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8");
   }
```

Comment: when i pass str ="At that time the LORD said unto me, &lt;span style=\&quot;color:#ff0000;\&quot;&gt;" ,then it return as it is "At that time the LORD said unto me, &lt;span style=\&quot;color:#ff0000;\&quot;&gt;"  no change is there.

Comment: i tried 1)  byte[] data = str.getBytes();
  try {
  str = new String(data, "UTF-8");
                URLDecoder.decode(str);
   } catch (Exception e) {
  // TODO Auto-  generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
   }
           2)Apache Commons lang libraray
              str = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(str);
           3)URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8");
but result is zero.The string is passed in it i get the same string in output.so my decoding code is same as encoding code.

Comment: I also tried online to see that whether this is possible or not but online it works here is the link of online http://coderstoolbox.net/string/      i pass my string here "&lt;span style=\&quot;color:#ff0000;\&quot;&gt;"  and decode then result is <span style=\"color:#ff0000;\">,but how to do this in android please suggest me any trick.

Comment: could u post your last but 1 comment in a proper way in your question itself? are u returning decoded string from decodeMethodUtf?

Comment: no i am not returning decoded string from the decodeMethodUtf.-Braj

Comment: u r neither printing decoded string(at least in ur last but 2 comment) nor returning it then how u know that its not decoded?

Comment: this is my decoded string &lt;span style=\&quot;color:#ff0000;\&quot;&gt;

Comment: String str = "&lt;span style=\&quot;color:#ff0000;\&quot;&gt;";
          String decoded_string = decdecodeMethodUtf(str);
          Log.e("", ""+decoded_string);//and this is the output = &lt;span style=\&quot;color:#ff0000;\&quot;&gt;
          public String decodeMethodUtf(Str)
          {
             return URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8");
          }

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @DEVENDRA. From you post I was able to decode the returned JSON string that had been encoded

The magic was in your statement:

```
String decoded_string = decdecodeMethodUtf(response);
```

==============================================

```
String path = Protocol.SERVER_URL + Protocol.kMyPhp  + "?userId=" + userId + "&firstLoad=" + isRefresh + "&taskId=" + taskId;

// Make call to .php file and get response from DB

String response = HttpApi.sendRequest(path, null, null);

if (response == null) return null;

// Decode the response to replace ASCII Encoding Reference with Special Characters

String decoded_string = decdecodeMethodUtf(response);
Log.e("", ""+decoded_string);
response = decoded_string;

Log.i("response", response);
return response;
```